# How to split array into two array

Tags: php, arrays

i was working on array using PHP lang.  I got following output by rotating for loop.
Now want to split this into two different array. Any one please guide me to split into two different array... Like into a[0] = 810 and b[0] = 44

as well as , i am trying to sort it without changing the values for example sorting max value  a[0] =  840 & b[0] = 87

```
Array
(
    [0] => 810/44
    [1] => 0/280
    [2] => 73/279
    [3] => 0/278
    [4] => 0/277
    [5] => 0/276
    [6] => 840/87
    [7] => 0/275
    [8] => 0/274
    [9] => 0/273
    [10] => 6/271
    [11] => 0/272
    [12] => 0/269
    [13] => 3/267
    [14] => 0/268
    [15] => 3/259
    [16] => 124/108
    [17] => 82/239
    [18] => 221/238
    [19] => 30/160
    [20] => 3/161
    [21] => 65/168
    [22] => 73/169
    [23] => 0/170
    [24] => 0/248
    [25] => 192/226
    [26] => 209/222
    [27] => 80/223
    [28] => 273/182
    [29] => 79/183
    [30] => 73/184
    [31] => 73/185
    [32] => 6/186
    [33] => 73/187
    [34] => 0/188
    [35] => 48/270
    [36] => 138/190
    [37] => 370/191
    [38] => 152/192
    [39] => 12/200
    [40] => 200/210
    [41] => 0/213
    [42] => 21/212
    [43] => 124/214
    [44] => 0/215
    [45] => 0/216
    [46] => 133/217
    [47] => 6/260
    [48] => 73/285
    [49] => 73/284
    [50] => 0/283
    [51] => 73/286
    [52] => 73/287
    [53] => 0/288
    [54] => 73/289
    [55] => 0/290
    [56] => 76/291
    [57] => 76/292
    [58] => 0/293
    [59] => 0/294
    [60] => 0/295
    [61] => 0/296
    [62] => 0/297
    [63] => 3/298
    [64] => 0/299
    [65] => 0/300
    [66] => 3/301
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
$a = $b = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    list($a[$key], $b[$key]) = explode('/', $value, 2);
}
```

**EDIT**: To handle the sorting afterwards, you can use this:

```
array_multisort($a, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $b);
```

Comment: yes , i will use this only ... But before it divided into two array .. how we can sort it ?

Comment: Amazing it working fine !! Hey Please can give me your gmail please

Comment: @SandeepKamble all my contact info is available on my [user profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/283078/cbuckley).

Comment: I have invited you on gmail please add !

Answer (score 1):

```
  foreach($array1 as $a){

 $a = (string)$a

 $pos = strpos($a, '/')

  $first[] = substr($a, 0, $pos);
 $second[] = substr($a, $pos);

 }
```

not tested . . .but u can try something on these  lines

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
<?php 
$a = array();
$b = array();

$orig_array = array('810/44','0/280');

foreach($orig_array as $orig){
   $values = explode('/',$orig,2);
   $a[]=$values[0];
   $b[]=$values[1];
}
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 810
    [1] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 44
    [1] => 280
)    
*/
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this will work but sorting will not working in this passion

Comment: @Sandeep Kamble how do you want it sorted

Comment: okay , 1st i need to sort it by max value. Without changing the values for example sorting max value a[0] = 840 & b[0] = 87